# Condition Expression seems not to be taken into account on DynamoDB PutItem

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

It's one of the first times I'm using DynamoDB and have created a table for user accounts in my system.

Table definition follows:

```json
{
    "Table": {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "AccountId",
                "AttributeType": "B"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "Email",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "AccountId",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            }
        ],
        "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
            {
                "IndexName": "EmailAddress",
                "KeySchema": [
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "Email",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    }
                ],
                "Projection": {
                    "ProjectionType": "ALL"
                },
                "IndexStatus": "ACTIVE"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

<sup>Some fields have been omitted for brevity.</sup>

I am using Rusoto DynamoDB client and this is what the `PutItem` call looks like:

```rust
dynamodb_client.put_item(PutItemInput{
    item: account_doc.as_hashmap(),
    table_name: accounts_datastore_name,
    condition_expression: Some("attribute_not_exists(Email) and attribute_not_exists(AccountId)".to_string()),
    ..PutItemInput::default()
});
```

As far as I understand, this should have the following behavior: fail the transaction if there are documents that contain `Email` with the value that I'm supplying in the new document or `AccountId` with the value I'm supplying in the new document.

I've been able to submit the same document multiple times without any error from the service. The documents are all in the table.

Any ideas why this condition expression is allowing documents to pass?

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding what the condition does. It does NOT look at other records in the table, only the record you are `put`ting. Imagine the following two records:

```json
{
  "AccountId": "<some_unique_id_1>",
  "Email": "user@example.com"
}
```

and

```json
{
  "AccountId": "<some_unique_id_2>",
  "Email": "user@example.com"
}
```

Each of those will be saved because the `AccountId` value is different, meaning it's a different record in the table.

What your condition WILL do is keep you from writing a record with the same `AccountId` a second time. Because `AccountId` is the key to the record, and you are making sure the record you are writing doesn't have `AccountId` set, you will only be able to write the record if it is the first time it's being written. The `Email` part of the condition is actually not doing anything in this case.

There are two options you can consider for what you want.

1. Switch the key to be the email address. That will make sure the email address is unique.
2. Use a [transaction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transactions.html) to write your record. This isn't quite as simple as it might sound. Alex DeBrie [has a pretty good article](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-transactions/) on using transactions.

Comment: *What your condition WILL do is keep you from writing a record with the same AccountId a second time* I don't understand why this is. I have specified both `AccountId` and `Email` fields in my condition.

Comment: *The Email part of the condition is actually not doing anything in this case.* why is this? Can I somehow exploit the fact the `Email` is added in a GSI?

Comment: The reason it's not doing anything is because if the `AccountId` exists you can't put the record, but if `AccountId` does not exist then neither can `Email`, since `AccountId` is the key. You can't leverage the GSI because the keys in a GSI are not unique.